# Apache Camel defining Route with an HTTP from

Tags: apache-camel

How to define a Camel Route with an HTTP for the "from" endpoint?

My goal is to define a Route that when there is an HTTP request, a Message will be enqueued on the ActiveMQ Queue.

I tried the following Route definition:

```
<route>
  <from uri="http://localhost:8181/cxf/crm/customerservice/customers" />
  <to uri="activemq:queue:LOG.ME" />
</route>
```

From a browser, I access the URL:

```
http://localhost:8181/cxf/crm/customerservice/customers/123
```

I had verified that the HTTP request had reach the web service "customerservice", since I received an XML response from the web service. However, no Message was enqueued on the ActiveMQ Queue.

Below is the Route definition that processes Messages from the ActiveMQ Queue.

```
<route>
  <from uri="activemq:queue:LOG.ME" />
  <multicast>
    <pipeline>
      <bean ref="processor1" method="handle" />
      <to uri="mock:result" />
    </pipeline>
    <pipeline>
      <bean ref="processor2" method="handle" />
      <to uri="mock:result" />
    </pipeline>
  </multicast>
</route>
```

I verified that nothing was enqueued to the ActiveMQ, because the "handle" method of my beans "processor1" and "processor2" was not executed.

How to define a Camel Route with an HTTP for the "from" endpoint?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to listen to HTTP requests, then you need either to use the [servlet](http://camel.apache.org/servlet) component if you are running inside a web application or the [jetty](http://camel.apache.org/jetty) component which embedds a simple http server.

Both have good documentations and examples.

The http and http4 components are for producers only (`<to ... />`).

Comment: Thanks. I'm exploring now on using the Jetty component of ServiceMix.

Comment: You also have some OSGi example/docs on the http://camel.apache.org/servlet component for running in karaf/SMX.

Answer (score 2):

To listen to incoming http requests a proxy can be set up using jetty or cxf component which will then invoke the web service as well as log a message to activemq.

For example,

```
from("jetty:http://localhost:8282/xxx").
     to("http://localhost:8181/cxf/crm/customerservice/customers").
          to("activemq:queue:LOG.ME");
```

Now, to access the web service the proxy can be invoked as `http://localhost:8282/xxx`, instead of directly calling the web service. A proxy can be set up using the cxf component too, it is well documented.

Comment: Doing so, the Web Service did not start correctly. From the console of ServiceMix, I found the display,       "Bundle cxf-jaxws-blueprint is waiting for dependencies [(&(component=jetty)(objectClass=org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver))]"

Comment: From my pom.xml, I already added the necessary dependencies, "camel-jetty" with groupId org.apache.camel and appropriate version 2.10.3

Comment: I was modifying the sample ServiceMix project "cxf-jaxws-blueprint". On my blueprint.xml, I added     <route><from uri="jetty:http://localhost:8282/xxx"/><to uri="/HelloWorld" /></route>

Comment: The item     "Bundle cxf-jaxws-blueprint is waiting for dependencies [(&(component=jetty)(objectClass=org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver))]" was resolved when I issue the command on the ServiceMix console, features:install camel-jetty

Comment: Having camel-jetty in the project pom does not make it available to the container. If you are using an osgi container, the required package either needs to be part of the deployed bundle or the bundle also needs to be deployed, in this case camel-jetty bundle.

Comment: I am using ServiceMix as the container. How do I define on my POM, such that it will include the camel-jetty bundle? Thanks.

Comment: You can deploy camel-jetty jar bundle just like you deploy your application. Or as i said earlier you can include the dependencies in your application bundle. Take a look at [maven-bundle-plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html).